# How to render label and element separately in a zend form using DOJO element

Tags: zend-framework, dojo, zend-form

i've created a standard zend form with some simple zend element and one DOJO date picker.

```
$fromDate = new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_DateTextBox('fromDate');
$fromDate->setLabel('From Date')
            ->setDatePattern('dd-MM-yyyy');
$this->addElement($fromDate);
```

It works as expected. i can select the date from the associated dropdown.
But is it possible to render the label as well as the element separately?

On the ordinary zend elements i use the following in my view:

```
<?php echo $this->form->headline->renderViewHelper() ?>
```

to render the element and to render the label:

```
<?php echo $this->form->headline->renderLabel() ?>
```

(I'm not sure about the 'renderLabel' function' i can't find an example right now )

Is it possible to render the label and element separately on the DOJO element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->renderLabel()` works with both Zend_Form object or Zend_Dojo_Form

However, when you're using Zend_Dojo_Form, you must use `->renderDijitElement()` instead of `->renderViewHelper()`.